# Controlling linux keyboard, mouse, and clipboard from windows machine

Tags: synergy

I have done my searching and have referenced 
[Remote control a computer using another computer](https://superuser.com/questions/85884/remote-control-a-computer-using-another-computer)
[Remote screen control](https://superuser.com/questions/79322/remote-screen-control)

However, I am running into problems on the setup of synergy, and I think the workplace router or switch may be a problem. I have used synergy successfully at home on my network.

My Windows 7 machine is reporting 4 IP addresses and my Ubuntu is reporting 1 ip address.

I've tried all 5 possible configurations (Ubuntu as host, and Windows as 4 possible hosts).

I cannot get the computers to connect to each other. Any help?

Comment: You'd need to include many more specifics if you want help with synergy -- configuration, messages or symptoms, etc. Or, why not just use (free) VNC;  is the issue your need for the clipboard? The system you want to control is the host, if that was part of your question. Also the question you reference seems to be Win-to-Win; using linux constrains you from some solutions.

Comment: The 2nd reference shows a linux computer and windows computer side by side with 1 mouse, 1 keyboard, which is exactly what I want. I have also verified this setup at home. I didn't know about VNC. I will look into it. Yes I need a keyboard. Is VNC more or less SSH into the linux? I need mouse and clipboard functionality preferably

Comment: Start here: http://www.realvnc.com/new-to-vnc/ . Sorry I missed the 2nd link as separate. You can tunnel VNC through SSH per http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/vnc/sshvnc.html and others. Very commonly used, so lots of documentation & help available if it does what you want.

Comment: I found that using Synergy in 32 bit solved the problem. Even though both machines are 64 bit. Solved! xD